# htaccess to add https to url except for 1 directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

```
#ADD HTTPS TO URL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/hd/209$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I'm trying to force ssl for all the pages on the site except for /hd/209

I've tried the code above but it still forces that /hd/209 to ssl

Answer (score 0):

I will add a redirect for folder

redirect 301 /folder/ https://domain.com/carpinteria-aluminio-mallorca/

Comment: The /hd/209 directory isn't really a directory I'm using mod_rewrite to make it see like a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser cache and restart it.

Then replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (?!^hd/209)^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```